# ¿Es posible hacer mi propia API de un sitio que no tenga API con Python?

Tags: python, api

Si una pagina/servicio web no ofrece una API para que mis programas interactuen con el sitio, que librerias puedo utilizar para hacer mi propia API del sitio que quiero utilizano Pyhton o alguna otra herramienta ?

Comment: no se de python, pero puede que esto te ayude -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7wB__M9fdw&list=PLgGfaPLP959bTiKYokXPkO15atkXYyYOz y esto  http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~gawron/python_for_ss/course_core/book_draft/web/web_intro.html Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Siempre es posible crear tu propia `API`, ya que un [servicio web](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servicio_web) es independiente de la aplicación que utilice, como así también es independiente del lenguaje de programación. Por lo tanto puedes tener el servicio web (tu api) programada en Java y la app que lo consume en Python. 
Lo único que necesitas es un servidor que aloje el servicio web  para poder interactuar con la `API`.

Te recomiendo que utilices [`REST`](http://asiermarques.com/2013/conceptos-sobre-apis-rest/)  para la construcción del `servicio web`. Y las librerias a utilizar depende del formato de la respuesta del servicio, te aconsejo que tu servicio web interactue con objetos `JSON`. Saludos